# How to use RCurl to scrape webpage using javascript for navigation?

Tags: javascript, r, web-scraping, rcurl

I have a link like this one:

http://webfund6.financialexpress.net/clients/zil/pricetable.aspx?User=PUBLIC&Region=ROW&Range=VISTA&Currency=HKD

Which I want to scrape the fund prices in daily basis, I am able to the scrape first page using `XML` and `RCurl` package in R, but for the remaining funds in the second page and afterwards, it is navigated by javascript (`javascript:SetPageIndex('1');`).

How can I scrape the javascript-navigated pages?